# Best way to make app UI responsive?? [ FLUTTER ]

Tags: android, flutter, responsive

I am new in flutter. After building my first app in a flutter, I am getting an issue in making my flutter app UI responsive.

Please suggest your best approach to make my flutter app responsive.

I implement this code to make it responsive.

```
Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
```

but i am still having error like this

```
error: The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer. (implicit_this_reference_in_initializer at [demo_app] lib\pages\language_page.dart:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MediaQuery`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

```
Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

Container(
  height: screenSize.height / 10,
  width: screenSize.width / 10
);
```

Comment: thanks for edit @dumazy